# Showing categories and subcategories with posts

Tags: posts, loop, categories, children

Basically as the title says I want to get list of categories and subcategories and then posts(with links to them) for those categories/subcategories.

This is the structure I'm trying to achieve:

- Category 1
  - Subcategory 1 within category 1
    - Post 1 within subcategory 1
    - Post 2 within subcategory 1
    - Post 3 within subcategory 1
  - Subcategory 2 within category 1
    - Post 1 within subcategory 2
    - Post 2 within subcategory 2
    - Post 3 within subcategory 2
  - Subcategory 3 within category 1
    - Post 1 within subcategory 3
    - Post 2 within subcategory 3
    - Post 3 within subcategory 3
  - Posts that have no subcategory
    - Post 1 with no subcategory
    - Post 1 with no subcategory
- Category 2
  - Subcategory 1 within category 2
    - Post 1 within subcategory 1
    - Post 2 within subcategory 1
    - Post 3 within subcategory 1
  - Subcategory 2 within category 2
    - Post 1 within subcategory 2
    - Post 2 within subcategory 2
    - Post 3 within subcategory 2
  - Subcategory 3 within category 2
    - Post 1 within subcategory 2
    - Post 2 within subcategory 2
    - Post 3 within subcategory 2
  - Posts that have no subcategory
    - Post 1 with no subcategory
    - Post 1 with no subcategory

Now so far after after reading everything I could found on the subject I have the following code:

```
<ul>   
    <?php 
        $get_parent_cats = array(
            'parent' => '0' //get top level categories only
        ); 

        $all_categories = get_categories( $get_parent_cats );//get parent categories 

        foreach( $all_categories as $single_category ){
            //for each category, get the ID
            $catID = $single_category->cat_ID;

            echo '<li><a href=" ' . get_category_link( $catID ) . ' ">' . $single_category->name . '</a>'; //category name & link
            $get_children_cats = array(
                'child_of' => $catID //get children of this parent using the catID variable from earlier
            );

            $child_cats = get_categories( $get_children_cats );//get children of parent category
            echo '<ul class="children">';
                foreach( $child_cats as $child_cat ){
                    //for each child category, get the ID
                    $childID = $child_cat->cat_ID;

                    //for each child category, give us the link and name
                    echo '<a href=" ' . get_category_link( $childID ) . ' ">' . $child_cat->name . '</a>';

                }
            echo '</ul></li>';
        } //end of categories logic ?>
</ul>
```

Now this code shows categories and subcategories well but I need to somehow loop through my posts and show them withing categories/subcategories.
I have also tried to use fallowing code:

```
    <?php
        // get all the categories from the database
        $cats = get_categories(); 

            // loop through the categries
            foreach ($cats as $cat) {
                // setup the cateogory ID
                $cat_id= $cat->term_id;
                // Make a header for the cateogry
                echo "<h2>".$cat->name."</h2>";
                // create a custom wordpress query
                query_posts("cat=$cat_id&posts_per_page=100");
                // start the wordpress loop!
                if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php // create our link now that the post is setup ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    <?php echo '<hr/>'; ?>

                <?php endwhile; endif; // done our wordpress loop. Will start again for each category ?>
            <?php } // done the foreach statement ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #container -->
```

This code shows all categories and posts within particular category, but the structure is not the one I want.
I have been trying to combine these two snippets of code for two days, but nothing I try gives me the result I want.
I am inexperienced with Wordpress and I could really use help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Complete code

```
<ul>   
        <?php 
            $get_parent_cats = array(
                'parent' => '0' //get top level categories only
            ); 

            $all_categories = get_categories( $get_parent_cats );//get parent categories 

            foreach( $all_categories as $single_category ){
                //for each category, get the ID
                $catID = $single_category->cat_ID;

                echo '<li><a href=" ' . get_category_link( $catID ) . ' ">' . $single_category->name . '</a>'; //category name & link
                 echo '<ul class="post-title">';

                $query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat'=> $catID, 'posts_per_page'=>10 ) );
                while( $query->have_posts() ):$query->the_post();
                 echo '<li><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
                endwhile;
                wp_reset_postdata();

                echo '</ul>';
                $get_children_cats = array(
                    'child_of' => $catID //get children of this parent using the catID variable from earlier
                );

                $child_cats = get_categories( $get_children_cats );//get children of parent category
                echo '<ul class="children">';
                    foreach( $child_cats as $child_cat ){
                        //for each child category, get the ID
                        $childID = $child_cat->cat_ID;

                        //for each child category, give us the link and name
                        echo '<a href=" ' . get_category_link( $childID ) . ' ">' . $child_cat->name . '</a>';

                         echo '<ul class="post-title">';

                        $query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat'=> $childID, 'posts_per_page'=>10 ) );
                        while( $query->have_posts() ):$query->the_post();
                         echo '<li><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
                        endwhile;
                        wp_reset_postdata();

                        echo '</ul>';

                    }
                echo '</ul></li>';
            } //end of categories logic ?>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Hello Bikash thank you for your help, but I need posts to show if there are no subcategories also I need posts to be permalinks.

Comment: You meant you don't want to show posts of intermediate categories and post of last category only!!

Comment: No no I want to show them but in case there is no subcategories I still want to show posts.
With code you gave if I have post in parent category it doesn't show. Look at my structure and you'll understand what I mean.

Comment: I've made an image to show you what I mean.
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzFnmSPdntJDeVA2MHNsM3I0Q2s/view?usp=drivesdk)  as you see in "kategorija3" posts are not showing because I have no subcategory but I still have posts in that category I also have posts in "kategorija1" which don't have subcategory and they also don't show.

Comment: if you want to show the post of parent category and child category in hierarchical form then you should use the same loop inside parent `foreach` loop also use `'cat'=>$catID` incase of parent `foreach` loop  parent  if you want grandchild category and more  you need to add more nested `foreach` loops and `wp_query`

Comment: use same loop before `$get_children_cats = array(
                'child_of' => $catID //get children of this parent using the catID variable from earlier
            );` in your code and  use ` 'cat' => $catID` this time

Comment: Can you maybe edit your answer and give me full code I'm trying to implement what you are saying but I'm making some mistake I can't make it work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60502/discussion-between-bikash-waiba-and-karadjordje).

Answer (score 1):

This function works right away, just make sure to change the names to your own taxonomy and post type. Feel free to read the comments for more clarification.

```
function ow_categories_with_subcategories_and_posts( $taxonomy, $post_type ) {
    $taxonomy   = $taxonomy;
    $post_type  = $post_type;

    // Get the top categories that belong to the provided taxonomy (the ones without parent)
    $categories = get_terms( 
        array(
            'taxonomy'   => $taxonomy,
            'parent'     => 0, // <-- No Parent
            'orderby'    => 'term_id',
            'hide_empty' => true // <-- change to false to also display empty ones
        )
    );
    ?>
    <div>
        <?php
        // Iterate through all categories to display each individual category
        foreach ( $categories as $category ) {

            $cat_name = $category->name;
            $cat_id   = $category->term_id;
            $cat_slug = $category->slug;

            // Display the name of each individual category
            echo '<h3>Category: ' . $cat_name . ' - ID: ' . $cat_id . ' - Slug: ' . $cat_slug  . '</h3>'; 


            // Get all the subcategories that belong to the current category
            $subcategories = get_terms(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'   => $taxonomy,
                    'parent'     => $cat_id, // <-- The parent is the current category
                    'orderby'    => 'term_id',
                    'hide_empty' => true
                )
            );
            ?>
            <div>
                <?php
                // Iterate through all subcategories to display each individual subcategory
                foreach ( $subcategories as $subcategory ) {

                    $subcat_name = $subcategory->name;
                    $subcat_id   = $subcategory->term_id;
                    $subcat_slug = $subcategory->slug;

                    // Display the name of each individual subcategory with ID and Slug
                    echo '<h4>Subcategory: ' . $subcat_name . ' - ID: ' . $subcat_id . ' - Slug: ' . $subcat_slug  . '</h4>';

                    // Get all posts that belong to this specific subcategory
                    $posts = new WP_Query(
                        array(
                            'post_type'      => $post_type,
                            'posts_per_page' => -1, // <-- Show all posts
                            'hide_empty'     => true,
                            'order'          => 'ASC',
                            'tax_query'      => array(
                                array(
                                    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                                    'terms'    => $subcat_id,
                                    'field'    => 'id'
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    );

                    // If there are posts available within this subcategory
                    if ( $posts->have_posts() ):
                        ?>
                        <div>
                            <?php

                            // As long as there are posts to show
                            while ( $posts->have_posts() ): $posts->the_post();

                                //Show the title of each post with the Post ID
                                ?>
                                <p>Post: <?php the_title(); ?> - ID: <?php the_ID(); ?></p>
                                <?php

                            endwhile;
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    else:
                        echo 'No posts found';
                    endif;

                    wp_reset_query();
                }
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
ow_categories_with_subcategories_and_posts( 'the_name_of_your_taxonomy', 'the_name_of_your_post_type' );
```